# MagicEightBall array

Tags: java

I have a questions about assigning string into array number.

I've already declared the string array, eg.

```
String[] answer = {"yes", "no", "maybe"};
```

How to set each of the strings into an array of integers without using this kind of method. For example:

```
String answer1 = yes;
int answerList[0] = answer1
```

I also got error saying

> C:\temp folder\MagicEightBall.java:50: error: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to intSystem.out.println(answer[Random.nextInt(answerList)]);

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MagicEightBall
{
    public static void main( String[] args)
    {//start main
        final int Array_Length = 20;

        String[] answer = {"It is certain", "Yes - definitely", "Most likely", "Yes", "Better not tell you now", "Con't count on it", 
                        "Outlook not so good", "It is decidedly so", "You may rely on it", "Outlook good", "Reply hazy, try again", 
                        "Cannot predict now", "My reply is no", "Very doubtful", "Without a doubt", "As I see it, yes", 
                        "Signs to point yes", "Ask again later", "Concentrate and ask again", "My source say no"};

        int answerList[] = new int[20];


        int userInput;
        String questions;

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 to keep playing or 2 to exit:");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

        } while (userInput < 1 & userInput != 2 || userInput >= 2);

        while (userInput != 2);
        {
            switch (userInput)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Please enter your questions below:");
                    questions = input.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Hmmmm....");
                    System.out.println(answer[Random.nextInt(answerList)]); 
                    break;

                case 2:
                    break;

            }
        }

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 to keep playing or 2 to exit:");
            userInput = input.nextInt();

        } while (userInput < 1 & userInput != 2 || userInput >= 2);

        System.out.println("Written by blabla");    
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `int anInt = aString;` should do?

Comment: Consider using `Enum` instead of `String`

Comment: Enums I don't like.  They're really inflexible, and a bit baroque.  I'd never replace a simple array of strings like this with a list of enums.  Yucky.

Comment: Well ... just don't agree. Enum is encapsulated unit, you can even create a method randomAnswer() on it which returns you one value unlike the arrays. May be matter of taste if the code were better structured ... but it's not :)

Answer (score 4):

With your edit, the question makes more sense.  But the answer's the same: the normal way of doing this is just to use only the array of strings you have.  You don't need a second array.

```
    // good!
    String[] answer = {"It is certain", "Yes - definitely", "Most likely", "Yes", "Better not tell you now", "Con't count on it", 
                    "Outlook not so good", "It is decidedly so", "You may rely on it", "Outlook good", "Reply hazy, try again", 
                    "Cannot predict now", "My reply is no", "Very doubtful", "Without a doubt", "As I see it, yes", 
                    "Signs to point yes", "Ask again later", "Concentrate and ask again", "My source say no"};

    // nope, lose it
    // int answerList[] = new int[20];

    // skip a bit...

    // just use the length of the answer array
                System.out.println(answer[generator.nextInt( answer.length )]);
```

That's it.

Comment: thank you. I just did exactly you told me, but when I try to compile it I got error saying " error: non-static method nextInt(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
System.out.println(answer[Random.nextInt(answer.length)]);" do you have any idea whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Oh, that's what I get for copying your code with out checking carefully.  `Random` is a class, your instance you named `generator`.  I'll fix it.

Comment: @thank you so much for your help. it compiles now. somehow my loop keep running on "please enter 1 to keep playing or 2 to exit:". I will try to modify my loop body and see how it goes

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to pass an array as a parameter for the method "nextInt", which only takes a number.
If I understand what you're trying to do, you can do this instead:

```
answer[Random.nextInt(answer.length)]
```

answer.length returns the size of the array, which will allow you to pop a random number within the range of the array.

Comment: @thank you so much for your help. it compiles now. somehow my loop keep running on "please enter 1 to keep playing or 2 to exit:". I will try to modify my loop body and see how it goes

Comment: I don't think you need the while-do loops. You could use a single loop that gets the input every time and then checks it - if it's 1, continue the loop, if it's 2, break.